# symfony2 - how to include a twig from a twig

Tags: php, symfony, include, twig

Learning sympony2 and I have hit a wall and have tried numerous solution but nothing seems to work, I keep getting the

> Unable to find template "ScoreBoardViewerBundle.Viewer.scoreboard_keeper.html.twig" in
>   ScoreBoardViewerBundle:Viewer:view.html.twig at line 15.

Here is my twig snipped:

```
{% if score_keeper=='sk' %}
{% include 'ScoreBoardViewerBundle.Viewer.scoreboard_keeper.html.twig' with {'score_keeper' : score_keeper} %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'ScoreBoardViewerBundle.Viewer.scoreboard.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Initially I had only the file name, like I seen on examples from this twig site: [Twig site](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) but that produced the same error. The twig files are found in the same directory.

What am I doing wrong? Also I get the same issue regardless which file I try to include. I did have some typos but they should be fixed.

Here is the Controller I was using and it was able to open both views correctly, I just noted some twig in each file was redundant so hence the changes

```
    public function viewAction($score_keeper)
    {
       //returns scoreboard view for score keeper
//       if($score_keeper=="sk"){
//        return $this->render('ScoreBoardViewerBundle:Viewer:keeper.html.twig',array('score_keeper' => $score_keeper));
//       }
       //returns scorboard view for all others
       return $this->render('ScoreBoardViewerBundle:Viewer:view.html.twig',array('score_keeper' => $score_keeper));
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem, doesn't this `{% include  'ScoreBoardViewerBundle:Viewer:scoreboard_keeper.html.twig'  %}` work?

Comment: Nope I get that error.  EDIT: Actually your solution will work. Mine does not have the semi colons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your `{% include %}` statements. You are supposed to use `:` instead of `.` to separate blocks in template name.

Try this:

```
{% if score_keeper=='sk' %}
{% include 'ScoreBoardViewerBundle:Viewer:scoreboard_keeper.html.twig' with {'score_keeper' : score_keeper} %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'ScoreBoardViewerBundle:Viewer:scoreboard.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I must be suffering from acute blindness. :)